# Extracting data from array after HTML form submission (keypress event)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So I have a HTML form with a `keypress` event listener recording the `charCode` of the key pressed and then convert that `charCode` to a String of the letter related to the key.

Each time a letter is entered to the form, a new entry is created in `input_array[]`.

I have each letter in the alphabet stored as a SVG within JS variables in a different part of my main.js file and I would like to be able to read what letters have been stored in `input_array[]` and then display the SVG appropriate to that letter on a new page once the form has been submitted.

I've tried using the method below to *extract* the data from the array, but it fires on the first keypress and therefore I can't get all of the array data to then display the 4 letters. I also feel like there has to be a more efficient way.

```
var letter_one = input_array[0];
var letter_two = input_array[1];
var letter_three = input_array[2];
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ohin/688rcat6/), to show a basic version of what I'm trying to do. If you open the console you will see how `input_array[]` is being created.

I'm still very new to this language, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you are recording all key presses instead of just grabbing the value in the input on submit? If someone types something in, does backspace, and types again, do you want the backspace and everything?

Comment: To be honest, I just presumed that I needed to record all key presses to record the data that was being entered. I only want the letters entered, so I can then show the SVG paths of that letter on the next page. I just can't figure it out. It's probably something so simple, but since I'm a n00b I'm missing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected, this is much simpler than you're making it :)

When the form is submitted you can just snag the value from the input:

```
function handleSubmit() {
  var val = document.getElementById('user_input').value;
  validate(val);
  console.log(val);
  var letter_one = val[0];
  var letter_two = val[1];
  var letter_three = val[2];
  var letter_four = val[3];
  return false; // stops POST for dev
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1htpm6ag/

That being said, if you are actually doing this on a POST then on the page you are POSTing to you'll have to snag this from the POSTed form data, which is entirely different. Are you trying to do this in client side JS or a POST handler?

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, @Ted A. I am trying to do this in client side JS (_I think_). I think this is enough information for me to continue on my path of banging my head off the desk until I get this project completed.

Comment: Happy to help. Hopefully the project gives way before your desk or head :)

Comment: Hi Ted, I am also having trouble getting an output from your code. Now, if I understood correctly then I should have the `handleSubmit()` function on the HTML page that form submits to?

Comment: My bad, it was a silly mistake. I have it working now. Thank you again, @Ted.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you correctly is sound like you want to do the following.

1. On Page 1 user enters text into textfield.
2. On Submit send that text to page 2.
3. On Page 2 convert that text into an array of letters to associate with SVG paths to display.

If the above is the case you need a lot less javascript.

- Page 1: Should only have your form with your text box and a submit button so the data is submitted to the next page using the GET method.
- Page 2: Here is where you will need the Javascript to retrieve that data sent across and process it into your array of letters. I would also filter for non-letter characters as well.

I have created an example form in the code below that submits to itself and then the javascript script tag will pull the variable from the url and process it into an array of letters. In your case you would move the Javascript to page 2.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(){
      function getParamValue(param) {
          var urlParamString = location.search.split(param + "=");
          if (urlParamString.length <= 1) return "";
          else {
              var tmp = urlParamString[1].split("&");
              return tmp[0];
          }
      }
      function isLetter(c) {
        return c.toLowerCase() != c.toUpperCase();
      }

      var user_input = getParamValue('user_input');
      var char_array = null;
      if(user_input !== ''){
        char_array = user_input.split("");
        char_array = char_array.filter(isLetter);
        for(var i in char_array){
          console.log('Char ' + i + ' = ' + char_array[i]);
        }
      }
    })();
  </script>
  <body>
    <form id="user_form" class="" action="?" method="GET">
      <input type="text" name="user_input" />
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have inputted your code, and though I'm not getting any errors, I am not getting anything logged to the console either on submission of the form. There are no other scripts getting in the way of yours, and everything is named the same too. I just can't figure why it won't output `char_array` to the console. [user_form fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ohin/ta1kszee/), [user_page fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ohin/c14pmjw7/)

Comment: Try running it from a local server and not inside a fiddle.. Fiddle is ok for simple examples but when it comes to things that take multiple pages it can act up some times because of how it's built. It is probably not passing the parameters from the form submit because of some way in which it is handling redirecting the form.